# Sidebar doesn't need scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following issue[image]

On the picture you can see a page, which consists of sidebar ( with the accordion tabs) and table (with some data). I want to do it in a way, (1) that when there is no expanded tab and I scroll the page, the sidebar stays, only the table moves down. (2) And when there is an expanded tab, the sidebar is scrolled as well. I tried with position: fixed, however it doesn't work, because it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled (it fulfills condition (2) only). If I use another type of positions, it doesn't fulfill condition (1)

Here you can see the expanded html tree:
[image]

div id=accordionsTable consists of the sidebar and table,
aside id=tabsFooter is the sidebar and div id=accordionTabs is the component with accordions,
div id=invoiceTableDetails is the component with the table

I will be really grateful, if you could give me some ideas or directions how can I fix this issue.

Comment: The automatically scrolling both is probably a challenge too far, but individually scrolling the table and sidebar can probably be done by adding a CSS property `overflow: auto` on the container elements (probably a `div` element surrounding the table and a separate `div` surrounding the menu). We need more code or a working example to help you out better.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering the variant with individual scrolls and I'm waiting for acceptance of my colleagues about this solution, because there is no other variants I think.

Comment: To be honest, if I'm on a page where both scroll at the same time but are not the same length that would give me such a weird feeling. It probably doesn't make the user experience better and is a lot more work. I cannot think of a single example where this has been implemented and that is probably for a reason.